# Pytdx does exist in Jupyter-lab, but it says that Pytdx is not a package

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I run Python code in Jupyter-lab, I get a message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytdx.crawler'; 'pytdx' is not a
> package.

However pytdx is on my computer, in the python310 directory, when I run !pip show pytdx in jupyter lab, it shows that pytdx exists. When I run the same Python code in Python 3.10（64-bit)， I don't get this error message. What is wrong, how can I fix it?

when I run

> import sys print(sys.version)

in Jupyter-lab,
I get

```
3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the Python installation that Jupyter is using?  How do you know?

Comment: Either you're not running the same python binary as the one associated with pytdx, or your script is named pytdx or something else is the issue with your Jupyter-lab env.

Comment: Yes, one of my scripts is named pytdx, thank you.